# How to get last added added user's UID from Authentication

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, navigation

## Requirement

I want to create a condition that if

```
_auth.currentUser?.uid is now equal to uid of lastly added user navigate to page 1 else navigate to page 2.
```

Can someone help me a way to get the uid of lastly added user's uid.
I have used

```
import 'package:flutterfire_ui/auth.dart';
```

to use FirebaseAuthentication. Once the user is signedup and signed in I need to save it's details against its UID. After signing in i am navigating it to a page where the user need to fillup the details form. What should I do not to load that page if the user is not new and already have provided its details at the time of signup. I am using CurrentUser Uid and saving it into a document in firebase with other credentials. Need you help.

## This is my HomePage

```
import 'package:deliveryapp/profile.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutterfire_ui/auth.dart';

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'ABC App',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
        ),
        outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
            style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
              minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
              textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              primary: Colors.white,
            )
        ),
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'SignIn SignUp'),


    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return const ProfilePage();
            } else {
              return RegisterScreen(
                headerBuilder: (context, constraints, _) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: 1,
                      child: Image.network('https://firebase.flutter.dev/img/flutterfire_300x.png'),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                subtitleBuilder: (context, action) => Padding( padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
                  child: Text(action == AuthAction.signIn
                      ? 'Login to Enter ABC Delivery App'
                      : 'Register to Enter ABC Delivery App'
                  ),
                ),
                footerBuilder: (context, _) => const Padding( padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                  child: Text(
                    'Thank you for being the part of the ABC Family', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),

                  ),
                ),
                providerConfigs: const [
                  EmailProviderConfiguration(),
                ],

              );
            }
          }
      );
}
```

## The page is navigated to this page.

```
import 'package:deliveryapp/riders.dart';
import 'package:deliveryapp/vendors.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
class ProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: const Text("Update Profile", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
                onPressed: () => FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(),
              ),

            ]
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(120),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children:  [
            //   const SizedBox(
            //     height: 20.0,
            //   ),
              const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                child: Text('Register As', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),),
            //
             ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 40.0,
              ),
               TextButton(
                 onPressed: ()=>Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => const VendorProfilePage())),
                 child: Text('Vendor'.toUpperCase(),style: const TextStyle(
                     fontSize: 12, wordSpacing: 5, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                 )),
               style: ButtonStyle(
                 padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(const EdgeInsets.all(25)),
                 foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
                 backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blueGrey),
                 shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                   RoundedRectangleBorder(
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                       side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black)
                   )
                 )
               ),
               ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 50.0,
              ),
              const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                child: Text('Or', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),),
                //
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 50.0,
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: ()=> Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => const RiderProfilePage())),
                child: Text('  Rider  '.toUpperCase(),style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12, wordSpacing: 5, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                )),
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(const EdgeInsets.all(25)),
                    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blueGrey),
                    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                            side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black)
                        )
                    )
                ),
              ),


            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

## This is Rider Profile Page

```
import 'package:deliveryapp/profile.dart';
import 'package:deliveryapp/service/local_push_notification.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final uid = _auth.currentUser?.uid;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  LocalNotificationService.initialize();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const RiderProfilePage() ,
    );
  }
}
class RiderProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RiderProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RiderProfilePageState createState() => _RiderProfilePageState();
}

class _RiderProfilePageState extends State<RiderProfilePage> {

  final CollectionReference _riders =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('riders');


  final TextEditingController _rnamecontroller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _rphonecontroller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _raddresscontroller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _rstatuscontroller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _uidcontroller = TextEditingController();



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text("Rider Profile", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
            onPressed: () => FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.backspace),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => const ProfilePage())),
          ),

        ],

      ),

          body:
          Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget> [
                Text(uid!, style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                TextField(
                  controller: _rnamecontroller,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: _rphonecontroller,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Phone No'),
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: _raddresscontroller,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Address'),
                ),


                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Save'),
                  onPressed: () async{
                    final String rname = _rnamecontroller.text;
                    final String rphone = _rphonecontroller.text;
                    final String raddress = _raddresscontroller.text;

                      await _riders.add({"rname": rname, "rphone": rphone, "raddress": raddress, "rstatus": 1, "uid": uid!});
                      _rnamecontroller.text = '';
                      _rphonecontroller.text = '';
                      _raddresscontroller.text = '';
                      _rstatuscontroller.text = '1';
                      _uidcontroller.text = 'uid';
                      return;




                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          );

  }
}
```

## This is VendorProfilePage

```
import 'package:deliveryapp/profile.dart';
import 'package:deliveryapp/service/local_push_notification.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final uid = _auth.currentUser?.uid;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  LocalNotificationService.initialize();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const VendorProfilePage() ,
    );
  }
}
class VendorProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const VendorProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VendorProfilePageState createState() => _VendorProfilePageState();
}

class _VendorProfilePageState extends State<VendorProfilePage> {

  final CollectionReference _vendors =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('vendors');


  final TextEditingController _vnamecontroller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _vphonecontroller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _vaddresscontroller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _vlatcontroller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _vlongcontroller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _vstatuscontroller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _uidcontroller = TextEditingController();




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text("Vendor Profile", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
            onPressed: () => FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.backspace),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => const ProfilePage())),
          ),

        ],

      ),

      body:
      Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget> [
          Text(uid!, style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
          TextField(
            controller: _vnamecontroller,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'User Name'),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _vphonecontroller,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Phone No'),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _vaddresscontroller,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Address'),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _vlatcontroller,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Longitude'),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _vlongcontroller,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Latitude'),
          ),


          ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('Save'),
            onPressed: () async{
              final String vname = _vnamecontroller.text;
              final String vphone = _vphonecontroller.text;
              final String vaddress = _vaddresscontroller.text;
              final String vlat = _vlatcontroller.text;
              final String vlong = _vlongcontroller.text;

                await _vendors.add({"vname": vname, "vphone": vphone, "vaddress": vaddress, "uid": uid!, "vlat": vlat, "vlong": vlong, "vstatus": 1});
                _vnamecontroller.text = '';
                _vphonecontroller.text = '';
                _vaddresscontroller.text = '';
                _uidcontroller.text = 'uid';
                _vlongcontroller.text = '';
                _vlatcontroller.text = '';
                _vstatuscontroller.text = '1';

                //return;




            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

I am a new student of Flutter. Giving me self challenges to develop a full stack application. I am trying to make a good logic but failing again and again. Need your help and support.

Comment: Welcome to SO. WHOA! That's a whole lot of code for us to parse through. Best practice here on SO is to provide a short code example of the issue, along with troubleshooting. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please troubleshoot and shorten the code in the question and clarify what's being asked and we'll take a look!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving the Uid to a Users collection in FireStore you could potentially add a 'created_at' field as well within the document.You could then query all the users and see which one was the most recent by looking at the created_at field.

Wherever you are saving the uid of a user to the document, you could implement a funtion to add that field as well. Something like this could work:

```
Future<void> addUserIdCreatedAtToFireStore() async {
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  if (uid != null) {
    users.doc(uid).set({'userId': uid, 'created_at:': now});
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```